# Pig Schema error Unexpected character ':'

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to create a pig schema with `2B:chararray` as name of one column. 
It is giving me an error message

> 2B:chararray Unexpected character ':'

If that is removed the schema is created. What is the problem here?

the schema is

```
load 'Batting.csv' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',','YES_MULTILINE','NOCHANGE','SKIP_INPUT_HEADER') as (yearID:int, sting:chararray, teamID:chararray, lgID:chararray, G:chararray, G_batting:chararray, AB:chararray, R:chararray, H:chararray, 2B:chararray);
```

[image: click here for sample csv image]

Comment: Are you sure, you have the correct number of columns in your batting.csv file? Its quite possible that there is not enough columns in your file.

Comment: yes i have it. I updated the image in the question please check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be following the Java variable naming conventions and hence has to abide those rules.

> Rules for naming java variables: All variable names must begin with a letter of the alphabet, an underscore, or ( _ ), or a dollar sign ($).